# Implementing soft time window constraints with time_matrix dependent on vehicle types

Tags: vehicle-routing, or-tools, cvrptw

I am solving a CVRPTWPD using Google ORTools. Here, objective is to minimize the travelled distance and not time.

I have start locations for each vehicle but arbitrary end locations are possible. I have added dummy node for arbitrary end locations.

Also, there are more than one type of vehicle and time matrix depends on the speed of type of vehicle.
I need to implement soft time window constraints for all orders.
Based on various sources on internet and my understanding of ortools, I'm implementing it as follows:

```
travel_time_callback_indices = []

for _, row in driver_df.iterrows():
    speed = row["speed_meter_per_sec"]
    vehicle_travel_time_callback = partial(travel_time_callback, speed_in_mps=speed)
    travel_time_callback_index = routing.RegisterTransitCallback(vehicle_travel_time_callback)
    travel_time_callback_indices.append(travel_time_callback_index)


dimension_name = 'Time'
routing.AddDimensionWithVehicleTransitAndCapacity(
    travel_time_callback_indices,
    7200,  # Max Slack
    [7200]*driver_df.shape[0],  # vehicle maximum travel time
    False,  # don't start cumul to zero
    dimension_name)

time_dimension = routing.GetDimensionOrDie(dimension_name)
```

Till here, it works fine. As soon as I add TW constraints as follows, kernel dies.

```
penalty = 1 # $1/second
# Add time window constraints for each location except depot.
for location_idx, time_window in enumerate(data['time_windows']):
    index = manager.NodeToIndex(location_idx)
    time_dimension.CumulVar(index).SetMin(time_window[0])
    time_dimension.SetCumulVarSoftUpperBound(index, time_window[1], penalty)
```

Please note that all the vehicle start locations and dummy node have been given the max possible time window.

I need to understand why is kernel dying? Is there any better way to implement soft time window constraints?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix this. I checked on following points:

1. time callback function must return an integer and not float.
2. You can not add time window constraints on depots.

````
penalty = 1 # $1/second
# Add time window constraints for each location except depot.
for location_idx, time_window in enumerate(data['time_windows']):

    if location_idx in data["depots"] + dummy_depot:
        continue    

    index = manager.NodeToIndex(location_idx)
    time_dimension.CumulVar(index).SetMin(time_window[0])
    time_dimension.SetCumulVarSoftUpperBound(index, time_window[1], penalty)
```
````